# Rounded table borders

Tags: css, css-tables

I currently implement rounded borders on a table like so:

```
.tbor {
    border-width:3px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:lighten(@col-border,10%) darken(@col-border,10%) darken(@col-border,10%) lighten(@col-border,10%);
    border-radius:12px;
}
.tbor>tr>td, .tbor>thead>tr>td, .tbor>tbody>tr>td, .tbor>tfoot>tr>td, .tbor>tr>th, .tbor>thead>tr>th, .tbor>tbody>tr>th, .tbor>tfoot>tr>th {
    border: 1px solid @col-border;
    padding: 2px;
}
.tbor_tl {border-top-left-radius: 8px;}
.tbor_tr {border-top-right-radius: 8px;}
.tbor_br {border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;}
.tbor_bl {border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;}
```

This works fine, but it requires me to manually set classes on the top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right cells.

On another project, I have used the following rules for cells:

```
.tbor>thead>tr:first-of-type>td:first-of-type,.tbor>colgroup+tbody>tr:first-of-type>td:first-of-type,.tbor>tbody:first-child>tr:first-of-type>td:first-of-type,.tbor>tr:first-of-type>td:first-of-type{border-top-left-radius:8px}
.tbor>thead>tr:first-of-type>td:last-of-type,.tbor>colgroup+tbody>tr:first-of-type>td:last-of-type,.tbor>tbody:first-child>tr:first-of-type>td:last-of-type,.tbor>tr:first-of-type>td:last-of-type{border-top-right-radius:8px}
.tbor>tbody:last-child>tr:last-of-type>td:first-of-type,.tbor>tfoot>tr:last-of-type>td:first-of-type,.tbor>tr:last-of-type>td:first-of-type{border-bottom-left-radius:8px}
.tbor>tbody:last-child>tr:last-of-type>td:last-of-type,.tbor>tfoot>tr:last-of-type>td:last-of-type,.tbor>tr:last-of-type>td:last-of-type{border-bottom-right-radius:8px}
```

It's an ugly mess, and it relies entirely on all table cells being 1x1. It completely falls apart when any of the cells (escpecially the bottom ones) having `colspan` or `rowspan`.

Is there any way to do this? JavaScript is okay: it can be assumed that all table are static, or that dynamic tables have static first and last rows.

Comment: I'm noob in this , but why not `border-radius:1px 1px 1px 1px` instead of saying, top-left, bottom-right, bottom-left.... ?

Comment: Because I'm only setting one corner at a time?

Comment: Are these tables large? Tables with more than a few thousand rows load slowly, have you considered using spans instead of table cells? Can you provide a small fiddle with the worst case scenario that we can toy with a bit?

Comment: @TravisJ I fail to see how a thousand spans is any better than a thousand table cells. Anyway, the biggest table will be about 5x100 cells in size.

Comment: @Kolink - It has to do with the fact that the column widths are re-calculated as each row is rendered. As the rows grow in number, the re-calculation / re-rendering of every previous row begins to weigh on the browser a little (25,000 rows will cause a significant delay of at least 10 to 20 seconds). Each span would already have its style, width, etc. predefined and would not need those extra calculations and re-renderings. 5x100 cells will not have a noticeable (or any really) difference in rendering time so tds will be fine.

Comment: @Kolink - I guess I am still trying to picture what you are aiming to achieve. I made this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cuRwF/ , can you please explain what should change about it, or how it is different from the current issue you are looking at?

Comment: I use `table-layout:fixed` and `colgroup` a lot, especially on bigger tables.

Comment: @TravisJ [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/cuRwF/1/) an example of desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/2uSum/)***

Kind of an interesting situation. Really the non trivial part comes from identifying the bottom right corner table cell of the table. The others can be found through conventional means.

I am not sure if this is cleaner than your approach. Also, I used jQuery (sorry) for its `offset` functionality. The function can easily be taken if you do not include jQuery in your code, but for this example, and for a little brevity, I used it.

This approach will sort the four corners based off of their min/max top and left position with relation to the page.

```
(function (){
var tl = {};tl.x=99999;tl.y=99999;
var tr = {};tr.x=0;tr.y=99999;
var bl = {};bl.x=99999;bl.y=0;
var br = {};br.x=0;br.y=0;
$(".tbor td").each(function(){
    var cur = $(this).offset();
    if( cur.top <= tl.y && cur.left <= tl.x ){
     tl.x = cur.left;
     tl.y = cur.top;
     tl.td = this;
    }
    if( cur.top <= tr.y && cur.left >= tr.x ){
     tr.x = cur.left;
     tr.y = cur.top;
     tr.td = this;
    }
    if( cur.top >= bl.y && cur.left <= bl.x ){
     bl.x = cur.left;
     bl.y = cur.top;
     bl.td = this;
    }
    if( cur.top >= br.y && cur.left >= br.x ){
     br.x = cur.left;
     br.y = cur.top;
     br.td = this;
    }
});
tl.td.className += " tbor_tl";
tr.td.className += " tbor_tr";
bl.td.className += " tbor_bl";
br.td.className += " tbor_br";
})()
```

Anyway, this is a suggested alternative instead of determining by hand which td to place the class on.